# Converting Image into Base64 in json file issue

Tags: java, android, json, base64

I have a problem with encoding an image to send it to a json file. If i extract the image string to a txt and decode it, it works fine and i can see the encoded image, but when i put it to a json file, the imagestring changes when it meets "/" it converts it to "\ /" to the json file and if the imagestring changes line, then the json file adds "\n". This makes the extraction of the imagestring from the json file imposible, in order to view the image.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) secondImageV.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
  bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos2);
  byte[] imageBytes2 = baos2.toByteArray();
  imageString2 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes2, Base64.DEFAULT);

 sendPost(imageString1,imageString2,sendAlert);

public void sendPost(String im1, String im2, String alert) {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("name", compname.getText());
            json.put("hydrovalue", _hydrometerValue.getText());
            json.put("im1", im1) ;
            json.put("im2", im2);
            json.put("hydrohealth", check1);
            json.put("hydrorepair", check2);
            json.put("hydroalert", alert);
            json.put("stime", stime.getText());
            json.put("etime", etime.getText());
            json.put("comm", _comments.getText());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/lmz8i";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String Response : " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: `Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes2, Base64.NO_WRAP);` should deal with the unexpected line wrapping. The escaping of `/` (and possibly `+`) makes no sense if the value is double-quoted in the json text. Escaping would only make sense for non-standard ids.

Answer (score 0):

Use Base64 "URL-safe" encoding. Instantiate those encoder/decoders as follows java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder and java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate! I tried the Base64.URL_SAFE encoding and even though it surpasses the symbol "\ /"  problem, when i try to decode it to an image via several online decoder sites it does not show my image.

Comment: this is how its returned now: https://api.myjson.com/bins/fz4qe , but in this format i cannot decode it to the original image ...

Comment: i don't see any wellformed base64 on this api.myjson.com/bins/fz4qe

Seems there are \n between different base64 but anyway using https://www.base64decode.org/ i can't get any url.

Comment: Marco Lettieri thanks for the information mate!! I resolved my problem by using the replaceAll method at the imagestring :  imageString2  = iimageString2 .replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " "); , before I add it to the json file .